# Есть ли ошибки или проблемы в коде

Tags: c++, ооп, инспекция-кода

Я начал изучать C++ ООП. И придумал вот такой пример с фабриками по добыче угля и железа.

```
    class Factory {
    int productSpeed;
    int quantityProduct;
public:
    int GetQuantityProduct() { return quantityProduct; }
    Factory(int speed) : productSpeed(speed), quantityProduct(0){}
    void Produce() { 
        cout << "Идет добыча ресурса" << endl;
        quantityProduct += productSpeed;
    }
};

class IronFactory : public Factory{
public:
    IronFactory() : Factory(10) {
        cout << "Открытие шахты железной руды!" << endl;
    }
};

class CharcoalFactory : public Factory {
public:
    CharcoalFactory() : Factory(20) {
        cout << "Открытие шахты угля!" << endl;
    }
};

class Furnace {
    int charcoal = 0;
    int ironore = 0;
    int ironingot = 0;
public:
    int GetIronIngot() { return ironingot; }
    Furnace(int ore = 0, int coal = 0) : charcoal(coal), ironore(ore) { }
    void Smelting() {
        if (charcoal < 2 || ironore < 1)
            cout << "Не хватает ресурсов для выплавки" << endl;
        else {
            charcoal -= 2;
            ironore--;
            ironingot++;
        }
    }
    void SmeltingAll() {
        while (ironore >= 1 && charcoal >= 2) {
            ironingot++;
            ironore--;
            charcoal -= 2;
        }
        cout << "Плавка завершена!" << endl;
    }
};
```

Есть класс Factory в котором определенные поля, конструктор, метод и гетер.

Так же классы IronFactory и CharcoalFactory которые наследуются от Factory.

И класс Furnace который делает из 1 руды железной и 2 угля 1 железный слиток.

Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я составил программу по правилам ООП. Если нет то скажите пожалуйста где ошибка и как правильно должно быть.

Вот пример использования фабрик

```
Factory factoryIron = IronFactory();
Factory factoryCharcoal = CharcoalFactory();
factoryIron.Produce();
factoryCharcoal.Produce();
Furnace furnace = Furnace(factoryIron.GetQuantityProduct(), factoryCharcoal.GetQuantityProduct());
furnace.Smelting();
cout << furnace.GetIronIngot() << endl;
furnace.SmeltingAll();
cout << furnace.GetIronIngot() << endl;
```

Comment: Честно говоря, не вижу большого смысла в таких упражнениях, не связанных с реальными задачами. Если по делу, то в глаза бросается отсутствие `const` на геттерах.

Comment: А в остальном есть какие нибудь недочеты или ошибки?

Comment: да нет, есть смысл в таких упражнениях. Я сам, когда программировать учился, и не такие сущности формализировал ;D Вроде научился решать и реальные задачи

Comment: Что касается идей ООП, то я бы добавил какую-нибудь виртуальную функцию, которая у железа работает иначе, чем у угля (придумайте сами суть, у вас богатая фантазия), а в базовом классе сделал ее чистой виртуальной (т.е. = 0), таким образом можно добавить полиморфизма. Ну и плавильное производство тоже бы унаследовал от Фабрики.

Comment: Самое простая виртуальная функция, которая приходит в голову, это распечатка "идет добыча железа" и "идет добыча угля" для каждого класса, т.е. что-то вроде `virtual void printResourceName() const;` или `virtual std::string getResourceName() const;`

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо придумывать задачи, тренировать фантазию, но нужно еще и выполнять осмысленные действия, а для этого во первых нужно иметь представление с какой сущностью имеешь дело и составлять логическую аюстракцию и т.д. и т.п. Но если не обратить на все это внимание и концентрироваться только на ваш код, то:

**ваши классы никак не используют закрытый член базового класса `productSpeed`**

, а сам базовый класс `Factory`  в своем  методе только инициализирует его значением количества руда. так что:

1. Нет смысла держать член  `productSpeed` и количество руда для всех обьектов должно  изменяться по ходу добычи, а если нет, то оно не должно быть частью обьекта, а быть статическим членом.

Ваши производные классы абсолютно бессмысленные в таком виде. Если же они существуют только для того, чтобы выразить какая это шахта, то лучше просто в базовом классе написать геттер(или сам конструктор) который для каждого значения  `quantityProduct` выдал бы вид шахты. Так что:

2. Нет осмысленных действий

С вашего позволения пропущу обсуждение по поводу класса `Furnace` и перейду к программе:

когда вы хотите работать с обьектами производного класса через базовый класс, лучше это делать через указатель или ссыльку базового класса, иначе  вы срезаете данные обьекта наследника. В вашем случаи таких данных у наследников нет, но вы можете в любой момент их добавлять, и тогда логика вашего кода будет  не той, что вы ожидали...

Comment: Не очень понял насчет productSpeed. Оно инициализируются, в конструкторе базового класса, а далее используется для увеличения количество товара.

Пожалуйста объясните момент с `лучше просто в базовом классе написать геттер(или сам конструктор) который для каждого значения quantityProduct выдал бы вид шахты`.

И вот последний момент не понятен на указатели и ссылки базового класса.

Если не сложно не могли бы вы привести легкий пример кодом. Мне его проще понимать.